# Handle boolean, null and undefined on nodejs/express 4.18 backend

Tags: node.js, json, express

The backend server is running nodes 18.x and express 4.18 and `express.json()` is used in routes.js:

```
   app.use(express.json());
```

The react native front end uses fetch to post. Here is one example of the data passed to backend:

```
let obj = {
  name:johndoe,
  admin:false,
  email:null,
}
```

On backend, the req.body returns an object which looks like below:

```
   let data = req.body;
   console.log("print out data: ", data);
```

print out:

```
{name:"john doe", admin:"false", email:"null"}. //data on backend
```

What the backend currently does is pass the data to a method and convert "null" to null and "false" to false. Here is the function:

```
convertObjNullBool : (obj) => {
   try {
        if (!self.isJSON(obj)) return false;  //check if the obj is JSON obj
        let temp = {...obj};
        obj.forEach(_key => {. //loop through obj one by one and convert the value as needed
            if (obj[_key] === 'null' || obj[_key] === 'undefined') {
                temp[_key] = null;
            } else if (obj[_key] === 'true') {
                temp[_key] = true;
            } else if (obj[_key] = 'false') {
                temp[_key] = false;
            };
        });
        return temp;
   } catch (err) {
        console.log("err in convertObjNullBool : ", err);
        return false;
   };
},
```

Is there a better way to handle the null, undefined and boolean in nodejs/express backend?

Comment: It is considered unsafe, but you can use `eval` function. If you decide to use eval, make sure you sanitize the input for vulnerability like `xss`.

Comment: Hi `Manish Kumar`, what is the security concern here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval! This will help.